# mysql 6 tables join together in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 6 tables: users, journals, files, flags, flag_details

```
users (id, avatar, fullname)
journals (id, container, container_id, user_id, title)
files (id, container, container_id, user_id, title)
flags (id, container, container_id, total)
flag_details (id, container, container_id, reason, comment, user_id)
trend_item (id, container, container_id, user_id)
```

Relation is:

```
if(flags.container='look') then flags.container_id = journals.id
```

So I take all records from journals table

```
if(flags.container='photo') then flags.container_id = files.id
```

So I take all records from files table

```
if(flags.container='trend') then flags.container_id = trend_item.id
```

So I take all records from trend_item table

So my view to be like this:

```
id | container | things      | total flag
1  | look      | 123 - guy   | 2
2  | photo     | 321 - budi  | 4
3  | trend     | 345 - elvis | 3
4  | look      | 876 - cans  | 6
```

So I got the query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (id), created_at, container, IF( container =  'look', (

SELECT a.container_id
FROM flags a, journals b
WHERE a.container_id = b.id
), IF( container =  'photo', (

SELECT a.container_id
FROM flags a, files b
WHERE a.container_id = b.id
), (

SELECT a.container_id
FROM flags a, trend_items b
WHERE a.container_id = b.id
) ) ) , total, 
`status`
FROM flags
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

But answer is subquery return more than 1 row.

There's any possible if all of that put together in one query?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can safely join all these tables with a single query, like this:

```
    SELECT fl.*
      FROM flags fl
 LEFT JOIN journals jo
        ON fl.container_id = jo.id AND fl.container = 'look'
 LEFT JOIN files fi
        ON fl.container_id = fi.id AND fl.container = 'photo'
       ...
```

Here's something of [a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a1ae/5) to illustrate the concept.

Comment: mysql returned an empty result set, any other ideas?

Comment: Damn, my bad. ) Of course, LEFT JOINs should be used in such a case.

Comment: Erm... I've already updated my answer and included a link to a demo.

Comment: thanks to raina, but my problem have solution not yet. coz i got 6 tables to join together. especially to showing a fullname from users table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t6.username AS username, MAX( t1.earn_status ) AS genx, MAX( t2.earn_status ) AS grnplus, MAX( t3.earn_status ) AS genpower, MAX( t4.earn_status ) AS genpro, MAX( t5.earn_status ) AS geextra 
FROM genx_commission t1 
    LEFT JOIN gen_plus_commission t2 ON ( t1.user_id = t2.user_id ) 
    LEFT JOIN gen_power_commission t3 ON ( t1.user_id = t3.user_id ) 
    LEFT JOIN gen_pro_commission t4 ON ( t1.user_id = t4.user_id ) 
    LEFT JOIN gen_extra_commission t5 ON ( t1.user_id = t5.user_id ) 
    LEFT JOIN users t6 ON ( t1.user_id = t6.id ) 
WHERE t1.user_id =1654
```